# Ligatures with Alegreya Font in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures

The following code does not create the expected ligatures (note that Alegreya is OTF):

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  SmallCapsFont={Alegreya SC},
  ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Italic},
  BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Bold},
  BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic},
  Ligatures=TeX,
]{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

fi ff fl

\end{document}
```

Defining `Ligatures=Rare`, `Historical`, and/or `Common` has no effect on output (as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33641/xelatex-fontspec-century-gothic-not-using-ligatures)).

Using the Alegreya package, however, *does* create the expected ligatures:

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

fi ff fl

\end{document}
```

However, I need to use `fontspec` in order to access some Icelandic characters. How can I achieve the ligatures in the first example?

Possibly related:

- [fj ligatures are not correctly mapped with glyphtounicode using Alegreya font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261274/fj-ligatures-are-not-correctly-mapped-with-glyphtounicode-using-alegreya-fon)
- [Activating fi and fl ligatures with fontspec for Berling font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/activating-fi-and-fl-ligatures-with-fontspec-for-berling-font)
- [Ligatures in Hoefler with XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6277/ligatures-in-hoefler-with-xetex)

Comment: I get ligatures with texlive 2015 and miktex.

Comment: Hmm, I have TeXMaker on Fedora 22; perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Texmaker is not relevant, but what is your texlive and xelatex version?

Comment: TeX Live 2014 with xelatex 2015.5.27 (I assume that's the correct xelatex information).

Comment: Set `Ligatures = Common`. That setting is default in newer versions of `fontspec`, but maybe you're running an old version.

Comment: Sorry, Sverre, I forgot to clarify: I tried that as well and it didn't work. (I just forgot to include it in the original post; I'll edit it.)

Comment: I get the same output with both documents. I have the opentype version of Alegreyra installed system-wide. What I'm not sure is how to tell which font is being used when I run the second document. In pdfTeX and LuaTeX, finding this out is easy. With XeTeX, I have yet to discover a method.

Comment: @cfr: In the default setting, xdvipdfmx runs in the quiet mode.
You will see used fonts by
`xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -v -E" foo.tex`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Thank you - this has been annoying me for some time!

Comment: When I compile the first document, XeTeX uses the opentype versions of the fonts. Yet the output is identical: ligatures work fine. I have version 1.004 of the font `Alegreya-Regular.otf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I run your code with tex live 2015 in Mac OS X, I just get a `font-not-found` error. As I see it, that's because I can't just say `\setmainfont{<name>}` if the font isn't installed on your system. But as [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264224/increase-word-space-between-words-in-small-caps#comment634156_264224) shows, other people claim that's wrong. In that case I have no idea why `fontspec` can't find `Alegreya`.

But at any rate, if I specify the file names of the fonts, as I usually do, everything works fine:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
fi ff fl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now this code is obviously just a minimal example to illustrate how you get the ligatures. Don't use that code and expect to get bold, italic, and small caps fonts. They have to be specified as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
    UprightFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-Regular},
    ItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-Italic},
    BoldFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-Bold},
    BoldItalicFeatures = {SmallCapsFont = *SC-BoldItalic}]
\begin{document}

fi ff fl

\textit{fi ff fl}

\textbf{fi ff fl}

\textbf{\textit{fi ff fl}}

\textsc{Small caps}

\textsc{\textit{Small caps}}

\textsc{\textbf{Small caps}}

\textsc{\textbf{\textit{Small caps}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure why you say that Alegreya is `.otf`, because the fonts that are distributed with TeX (which come from Google Fonts) are `.ttf`.

Also, you say that you need `fontspec` to access Icelandic characters. That's not correct, because all the characters of Modern Icelandic are included in the most common font encoding, `T1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Alegreya}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\TH etta er \'islenskt m\'al, og \th a\dh\ er ekki skrifa\dh\ \'a \"o\dh ru m\'ali.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As per your comment, I have no idea why this would give you an error about `T1` being undefined for Alegreya. I don't think the `Alegreya` package ever came without `T1` fonts, so that seems very odd to me. Update your `Alegreya` package and try again.

Comment: I also have the `.otf` versions installed system-wide. So it is quite possible that the OP has these installed for the system, regardless of what Google Fonts and TeX Live happen to favour. Do you know how to tell for sure which fonts XeTeX is *using*?

Comment: `Alegreya-Regular.ttf` in TeX Live is OK.
I downloaded `aregreya.zip` from
`http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/alegreya`
and tested
`\documentclass{report}`
`\usepackage{fontspec}`
`\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Alegreya-Regular.otf}`
`\begin{document}`
`fi ff fl`
`\end{document}`
There are no ligatures.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Nonetheless, your hint let me determine that the OP's first example compiles fine for me and it is using the opentype versions of the fonts. Ligatures work fine.

Comment: I too downloaded the font from fontsquirrel, and the command line tells me that the .otf font is being used in both examples. However, compiling Sverre's latter example returns the error `Font shape `T1/Alegreya(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead`. Perhaps it is, after all, just because I have TeX Live 2014?

Comment: After playing around with the several suggestions posted here, I seem to have found a fix (though that doesn't mean I understand it!). Clarifying the `.ttf` version of the font (as shown in the first example of Sverre's example) resulted in a `font-not-found` error. I thus used the `.otf` version of the font, which resulted in a *different* `font-not-found` error, this time for `Alegreya SC` in the `SmallCapsFont` option. I changed this to `SmallCapsFont={AlegreyaSC-Regular}` (which matches my font database) and suddenly all ligatures work perfectly, as do the Icelandic characters.

Comment: But alas, the above comment takes away my bold and italic characters (`font shape undefined`); any suggestions?

Comment: @Sam It's a bit hard to comment on your recent errors, because you can't get those from running my code (you can't get errors about SC with it). I just wrote a minimal example showing that you do get ligatures with the font. The reason you don't get a bold font with my code is because I didn't bother to specify a bold font. I assumed you knew how to set `fontspec` options, so I just focused on your question about ligatures. I can post a more complete example soon.

Comment: @Sverre, I had to tweak your code to match the `.otf` format and some of the font names on my machine, but everything is up and running now. My `fontspec` options problem was another result of `.otf` and `.ttf` confusion. Thank you so much for your patience and help!

Comment: @Sam It might be a better idea to just use the `.ttf` fonts to begin with, as there appears to be some problem with the `.otf` version you have.